# Libraries for making Eclipse plugin development easier?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm just learning Eclipse plugin development, currently for the purpose of adding a few simple custom commands that nobody else has bothered to implement. I've noticed that the Eclipse plugin API... leaves a lot to be desired. Are there any open source libraries which attempt to improve the plug-in development experience? (I've started to idly speculate about writing my own...).

I know Eclipse 4.0 is supposed to fix some of these issues long-term, but I'm unlikely to be able to move to it at work any time soon.

---

**Edit**

Here's an example of what I mean. This is an implementation of "hungry delete" functionality for emacs:

```
(defmacro hungry-delete-backward (&optional limit)
  (if limit
      `(let ((limit (or ,limit (point-min))))
         (while (progn
                  ;; skip-syntax-* doesn't count \n as whitespace..
                  (skip-chars-backward " \t\n\r\f\v" limit)
                  (and (eolp)
                       (eq (char-before) ?\\)
                       (> (point) limit)))
           (backward-char)))
    '(while (progn
              (skip-chars-backward " \t\n\r\f\v")
              (and (eolp)
                   (eq (char-before) ?\\)))
       (backward-char))))
```

And here is *part* of an equivalent implementation for Eclipse, not including the manifest file, plugin.xml, or the Activator for the plugin:

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
  IEditorPart editor = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditorChecked(event);
  if (!(editor instanceof ITextEditor)) return null;
  ITextEditor ite = (ITextEditor) editor;
  IDocumentProvider idp = ite.getDocumentProvider();
  IDocument doc = idp.getDocument(ite.getEditorInput());
  ISelection selection = ite.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
  if (!(editor instanceof ITextSelection)) return null;
  ITextSelection its = (ITextSelection) selection;
  int currentCursorPosition = its.getOffset();
  int deletionStart, deletionEnd;
  if (its.getLength() == 0) {
    deletionStart = currentCursorPosition - 1;
    deletionEnd = currentCursorPosition;
    FindReplaceDocumentAdapter frda = new FindReplaceDocumentAdapter(doc);
    while (Character.isWhitespace(frda.charAt(deletionStart)) && deletionStart > 0) {
      deletionStart--;
   }
   if (deletionStart != 0 && deletionStart + 1 != deletionEnd) deletionStart++;
  } else {
    deletionStart = its.getOffset();
    deletionEnd = its.getOffset() + its.getLength();
  }

  int deletionLength = deletionEnd - deletionStart;
  try {
    doc.replace(deletionStart, deletionLength, "");
  } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
    // Bad location, just ignore it.
  }
  return null;
}
```

The chunk of boilerplate at the top of the Java version, for example, could be easily replaced by a library.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the _issues_ that need to be fixed? It's not quite clear to me (and probably others as well) what you are talking about.

Comment: Sure, I can provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [Groovy-Monkey](https://github.com/fmjrey/Groovy-Monkey) or [Eclipse-Monkey](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Monkey_Overview), which allow you to do scripting to plug into Eclipse.  I don't know much about either project, nor do I know if they are actively maintained (actually I *know* that Eclipse-Monkey is no longer maintained).  But, these allow you to do emacs-like scripting inside of Eclipse.